# PHP exec() and display output

Tags: php, arrays, exec, echo

I've already seen a lot of solutions online for my problem but I have to admit that most of them did not work for me. Either they did just not output anything or even broke the upload function in my program, which actually works fine. I have written a little Script for the RaspberryPi enabling people to upload a hex file via http and have it automatically compiled using avrdude. Maybe I'm just too stupid to figure it out.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$all_ok = 1;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "upload/upload.hex")) {
        echo "Die Datei ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " wurde hochgeladen."."<br>";
        $all_ok=1;
    } else {
        $all_ok == 0;
        echo "Sorry, während dem Upload ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!"."<br>";
    }
    
    if ($all_ok == 1){
        $result = exec("/usr/bin/avrdude -c gpio -p m328p /var/www/upload/upload.hex -Uflash:w:/var/www/upload/upload.hex 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
        $result_array=explode(' ',$result);
        echo "Output: ".$result_array."<br>";
        echo "Exit status: ".$return_var."<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, während dem Kompilieren ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!";
    }   
?>
```

This is the current version of my program which sadly doesn't display anything more then

> Die Datei blink.hex wurde hochgeladen.
>
> Output: Array
>
> Exit status: 0

I think the problem is somewhere near

```
$result_array=explode(' ',$result);
        echo "Output: ".$result_array."<br>";
```

This was my latest vain approach, hopefully someone will enlighten me.

Comment: Could someone please enlighten me about why this got downvoted? I do not think the question is unclear, unuseful nor lacks research effort..
Also I would like to have a feedback from people that think I just posted something I should have not posted. A simple downvote is not enough (at least if you want my next questions to increase in quality ;) )

Comment: Not sure on why there is such a culture of down-voting here. Maybe concentrate on the two answers you have so far and interact with those people. That way you will earn reputation points and your experience on the forum will improve.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks to @Saty and you I already got the answer I needed. :) But it is still very discouraging to get downvoted this quickly without any explaination. I think someone who doesn't take the time to correct the question or ask further explaining questions shouldn't just downvote, because he - for a nanosecond - saw something that mispleased him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)**

> exec( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

It means second parameter is your output array. So do not assign the exec to any variable just use

```
 exec("/usr/bin/avrdude -c gpio -p m328p /var/www/upload/upload.hex -Uflash:w:/var/www/upload/upload.hex 2>&1", $output, $return_var);

print_r($output);
 $result_array=explode(' ',$output);
        echo "Output: ".$result_array."<br>";
        echo "Exit status: ".$return_var."<br>";
```

Comment: Yay, this was my mistake from the beginning on - Thank you very much! I appreciate your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

```
$all_ok == 0;
```

should be

```
$all_ok = 0;
```

Comment: uups, you're absolutily right - thanks for that one ;)